# addEventListener. Вывести переменную которая меняется

Tags: javascript

Есть JSON

```
{"data":[{"id_brand":"1","name":"BMW"},{"id_brand":"4","name":"Hyundai"}]}
```

Есть функция для построения таблицы

`

```
jsonToTable(json) {
        this.Array = [];
        this.tableElement.innerHTML="";
        var tblHead = document.createElement("thead");
        var tblTr = document.createElement("tr");
        this.tableElement.appendChild(tblHead);
        tblHead.appendChild(tblTr);
        for (var key in json[0]) {
            var tblTh = document.createElement("th");
            tblTh.innerHTML = key;
            tblTr.appendChild(tblTh);
        }
        var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");
        table.appendChild(tblBody);
        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var tblTr = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var key in json[i]) {
                this.Array[this.Array.length] = document.createElement("td");
                this.Array[this.Array.length-1].innerHTML = json[i][key];
                var t = this.Array.length;
                //Здесь проблема
                this.Array[this.Array.length-1].addEventListener("click",function () {
                    console.log(key);
                },true);
                tblTr.appendChild(this.Array[this.Array.length-1]);
            }
            tblBody.appendChild(tblTr);
        }
        console.log(this.Array);
    }
```

`

[image: Пример таблицы]

Так вот при нажатие на колонку id_brand срабатывает функция в addEventListener

> console.log(key);

И выводится 'name',хотя должно id_brand.
Я так понимаю, что это из-за того что key меняется в процессе выполнения цикла. Как исправить это?
**ПС Функция в классе.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда выполняются обработчики кликов, переменная `key` имеет значение из последней итерации цикла - как Вы уже заметили. С вызовом функции, которая возвращает функцию-обработчик, происходит "захват" значения этой переменной - в виде параметра, и замыкание, созданное вокруг возвращенной функции-обработчика, видит правильное значение `aKey` из конкретной итерации цикла.

```
this.Array[this.Array.length-1].addEventListener("click", (function (aKey) {
  return function() { console.log(aKey); };
})(key), true);
```

Comment: А в чем секрет?)

Comment: в замыкании значений переменых

Comment: каждый такой вызов `(function (aKey) {
  return function() { console.log(aKey); };
})(key)` возвращает новую функцию, которая в теле использует переменную aKey, а она в свою очеред в замкнувшей её функции